# iOS 12.3.1 Memory Debuging not working properly

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, memory-graph-debugger

Since I updated my iPhone XR to iOS 12.3.1 the memory debugging feature of XCode (10.2.1 (10E1001)) only shows grafic related targets. Neither my app target nor UIKit shows up.
Debugging an iPhone X with the same iOS version works perfectly fine.

[image: Debugger output]

What I already did:

1. Restarted my MacBook and iPhone multiple times
2. Cleaned the build folder
3. I deleted all device symbols
4. Deleted my app folder in the derived data folder

Any idea how to fix this?